# Spring data rest deserializing all associated resources as _embedded

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data Rest with JPA Repository and my entity (Customer) associations to other entities, including itself. The example below is of a self-referencing association though I have seen the same behavior for other associations as well.

I expected that when requesting for a customer resource,

> /api/customer/12345

the response JSON would "ONLY" have links to associated resources, however I see that the associated resources are also being de-serialized as "_embedded"

Is the "_embedded" de-serialization the default behavior or have I misconfigured something?

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "customer")
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, String> {

@RestResource
    Optional<Customer> findById(String id);

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

@Id
private String customerid;

private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "REFERENCE_CUSTOMER")
private Customer referenceCustomer;

}
```

localhost:8080/api/customer/12345

```
{
name : "N12345",
    _embedded : {
    referenceCustomer : {
    name : "R787657"
    }
},
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customer/12345"
        },
        "customer": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customer/12345"
        },
        "referenceCustomer": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customer/12345/referenceCustomer"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linked resources will be embedded when they don't have their own repository. If a repository exists then links should be included in the response. If this is not working expected then look through recent questions as there were 2 reporting that this did not work as expected in most recent SDR release.